# finding the bounding box of plotted text

Tags: r

I would like to jitter the text on a plot so as to avoid overplotting. To do so, I assume that I need a bounding box around the text component. Is there a way to get this?

For example, in base graphics:

```
plot.new()
text(.5,.5,"word")
text(.6,.5,"word") #does this overlap?
```

In grid there is a way to drop overlapping text, but I can't seem to find a way to access the code that figures out if overlapping has occurred.

```
grid.text(c("word","other word"),c(.5,.6),c(.5,.5),check=T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the `strwidth` and `strheight` functions can help here

```
stroverlap <- function(x1,y1,s1, x2,y2,s2) {
  sh1 <- strheight(s1)
  sw1 <- strwidth(s1)
  sh2 <- strheight(s2)
  sw2 <- strwidth(s2)

  overlap <- FALSE
  if (x1<x2) 
    overlap <- x1 + sw1 > x2
  else
    overlap <- x2 + sw2 > x1

  if (y1<y2)
    overlap <- overlap && (y1 +sh1>y2)
  else
    overlap <- overlap && (y2+sh2>y1)

  return(overlap)
}
stroverlap(.5,.5,"word", .6,.5, "word")
```

Comment: well, maybe nearly perfect. It doesn't get the tail of lowercase 'p' correct.

Comment: This assumes that the coordinates are located at the bottom left corner of each text. Is this true for `text()` in R? or is it actually located in the middle of the text? Will this still work if the latter is true?

Answer (score 2):

Package [`maptools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/maptools.pdf) has a function called `pointLabel`.

> Use optimization routines to find good
>   locations for point labels without
>   overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using base graphics it would be thigmophobe {plotrix}

"Find the direction away from the closest point"

Using lattice, Harrell has offered:

labcurve {Hmisc}

"Label Curves, Make Keys, and Interactively Draw Points and Curves"

Comment: I don't see how either of these can be used to figure out if two pieces of text overlap.

Comment: They can't, but they're generally useful tools for doing this sort of thing.  Not directly answering your question but possibly handy for other people who are browsing here in the future.  `labcurve` in particular has some machinery for plotting labels while avoiding overplotting