# putting text next to a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot with many "lines" in it (using points with type being l).

I would like to put a small piece of text next to them. I could do that all sort of ways, such as using mtext, but the problem is that there are many plots to be generated automatically, and there could be many lines in a single plot, so I would like the text to be placed *automatically* close to the line in an empty spot...

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: the directlabels package has some examples with lattice and ggplot2

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7611169/324364) question contains a pretty comprehensive catalog of tools for doing this kind of labeling. (But a perfectly general solution that _always_ works is basically impossible.)

Comment: As an alternative, consider using a `legend` and/or reducing the number of datasets in a single chart.  The latter may well increase comprehension.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?