# How can I label points in this scatterplot?

Tags: r, label, point, scatter-plot

Can you help me on putting labels on the following graph?

[image: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/7594/snap1034.png]

The code i use is:

```
valbanks<-scan("banks.txt", what=list(0,0,""), sep="", skip=1, comment.char="#")
valbanks

valj2007<-valbanks[[1]]
valj2009<-valbanks[[2]]
namebank<-valbanks[[3]]

percent_losses<-(valj2009-valj2007)/valj2007
percent_losses

abs_losses<-(valj2007-valj2009)
abs_losses

plot(abs_losses, percent_losses,main="Absolute Losses vs. Relative Losses(in%)",xlab="Losses (absolute, in miles of millions)",ylab="Losses relative (in % of January´2007 value",col="blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2,text(percet_losses, abs_losses,namebank))

text(percet_losses, abs_losses,labels=namebank, cex= 0.7, offset = 10)
```

and the data is:

```
Value_Jan_2007  Value_Jan_2009  Bank    #
49  16  Morgan_Stanley
120 4.6 RBS
76  10.3    Deutsche_Bank
67  17  Credit_Agricole
80  26  Societé_Generale
91  7.4 Barclays
108 32.5    BNP-Paribas
93  26  Unicredit
116 35  UBS
75 27   Credit_Suise
100 35  Goldman_Sachs
116 64  Santander
255 19  Citigroup
165 85  JP_Morgan
215 97  HSBC
```

Thank you very much

What is the option to put the label at the bottom, right, up, left,... ?

Summarizing: I want a graph similar that the one that is in the second message from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611169/intelligent-point-label-placement-in-r)
but there is no the code there.

What code i have to put?

---

if i put `text(percet_losses, abs_losses,namebank)`, i obtain nothing: the graph continue without changes.

Could you show me the code i need to put?

Thanks

Comment: By "second message", do you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612350/1451109) by @joran? If so, he specifically explained in this answer that he did not produced it programmatically but manually with an external software.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Your call to `text()` doesn't output anything because you inverted your x and your y:

```
plot(abs_losses, percent_losses, 
     main= "Absolute Losses vs. Relative Losses(in%)",
     xlab= "Losses (absolute, in miles of millions)",
     ylab= "Losses relative (in % of January´2007 value)",
     col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

text(abs_losses, percent_losses, labels=namebank, cex= 0.7)
```

Now if you want to move your labels down, left, up or right you can add argument `pos=` with values, respectively, 1, 2, 3 or 4. For instance, to place your labels up:

```
 text(abs_losses, percent_losses, labels=namebank, cex= 0.7, pos=3)
```

[image]

You can of course gives a vector of value to `pos` if you want some of the labels in other directions (for instance for Goldman_Sachs, UBS and Société_Generale since they are overlapping with other labels):

```
 pos_vector <- rep(3, length(namebank))
 pos_vector[namebank %in% c("Goldman_Sachs", "Societé_Generale", "UBS")] <- 4
 text(abs_losses, percent_losses, labels=namebank, cex= 0.7, pos=pos_vector)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For just plotting a vector, you should use the following command:

```
text(your.vector, labels=your.labels, cex= labels.size, pos=labels.position)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried `directlabels` package for putting text labels. In the case of scatter plots it's not still perfect, but much better than manually adjusting the positions, specially in the cases that you are preparing the draft plots and not the final one - so you need to change and make plot again and again -.

Answer (score 0):

You should use labels attribute inside plot function and the value of this attribute should be the vector containing the values that you want for each point to have.