# rotate the labels for a scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I know how to add labels to points in a scatter plot in R using the "text" command, as shown in this question: [How can i label points in this scatterplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229546/how-can-i-label-points-in-this-scatterplot)

But how can I rotate the text lable so that it runs vertically from the point?

Comment: In base R graphics, `text(..., srt = 90)` rotates the text by 90 degrees.

Comment: thanks so much, I missed the statement in the help that "par" settings could be used in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) + geom_point() + geom_text(angle=90,hjust=1.2)
```