# Labeling specific points in a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, labeling

I have a data frame with 1149 rows and 6 columns. I made a plot with the columns `protein number` on the x-axis and `iBAQ score` on the y-axis. Now, I want to add labels to the scatterplot for a few proteins of interest, protein numbers: 3, 5, 10, 20, 43, 72, 151.
My scatterplot code looks like this:

```
plot <- plot(Protein_number, iBAQ_score, xlab = "Proteins", ylab = "iBAQ score",
 main = 'Ccrosslinking on beads', abline(h=79961000, lwd=1, lty=2, col='green'),
 col=ifelse(Protein_number%in%Proteins_interest, 'red', 'black'),
 pch=ifelse(Protein_number%in%Proteins_interest, 19, 1),
 cex=ifelse(Protein_number%in%Proteins_interest, 1.2, 1),)
```

and it gives the following figure
[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L05qs.png)

The proteins of interest are colored red in the picture.
How can I add labels to my proteins of interest?

Comment: You can add labels to a base plot with `text()`. Check `?text` to find out about the different parameters. The principle is to provide 2 vectors `x`, and `y` for the position,  with the respective `labels`.

Comment: You should move `abline(.)` *outside* of the `plot` call. While it *appears* to work, what is really happening is that it is inadvertently assigned to the `type=` argument of `plot`, and when the code attempts to determine what "type" of plot it should make, it evaluates that expression (which has the side-effect of adding the horiz line to a plot); when the expression returns `NULL`, plot then ignores `type` and it just so happens to work. If you ever actually *use* `type=`, or if you have other unnamed args in front of it, then that will no longer work.

Comment: As far as adding labels, adding to @Ray's comment: you will likely want to subset your data (do you always store everything in vectors??) to the point of interest and then assign labels accordingly. I find that when plots get this "complex" (relatively speaking), the benefits and flexibility of `ggplot2` really shine, you might consider shifting to that plotting engine. I can't show you with your data (since we don't have it), but it would be straight-forward, and once you understand how ggplot layers things, it starts making a lot of sense. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I label points in this scatterplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229546/how-can-i-label-points-in-this-scatterplot)