# ggplot2 scatterplot and labels

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, label

I am attempting produce a scatter plot using the ggplot2 library. My data frame (called scatterPlotData) is in this form:

```
115 2.3
120 1.6
.
.
.
132 4.3
```

(The ... signifies many other similar values). Essentially, a 2 column data frame. I also have labels to go along with each of those points. Firstly, I'm having trouble with the scatterplot itself. I'm using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes("Distance (bp)", "Intensity"))
p + geom_point()
```

However, using the above code, I get the following plot:

[image]

Obviously, it's not a scatter plot. So, I'd be very helpful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Secondly, it's about the labels. I will have many datapoints which would have the risk of overlapping datapoints. How should I go about just putting on labels to each point using ggplot? Also, it [states](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16057/how-do-i-avoid-overlapping-labels-in-an-r-plot) that I could use the **directlabels** package to get a good overlap free labelled scatterplot using different colors, however, I'm not sure how I would go about that with `ggplot` as I haven't found any documentations regarding the use of **directlabels** with `ggplot`.

Any help with either (or both) question(s) are greatly appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it would be much more helpful if you provided a reproducible example the *precisely* described your data.

You should not be passing variable names in `aes` in quotes. I'm not sure where you got that from, there wouldn't be a single example of anyone doing that that I can think of (unless they were using `aes_string` which is specifically for that case).

**However**, it appears that you have an awkward variable name, i.e. `Distance (bp)`. This is non-standard and not recommended. Names should not have spaces in them. The best thing to do would be to rename that column to something sensible and then do something like:

```
p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(x = Distance_bp,y = Intensity))
p + geom_point()
```

If you do not rename the column, something like this *might* work:

```
p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(x = `Distance (bp)`,y = Intensity))
p + geom_point()
```

Note that those are backticks, not single quotes.

As for the overlapping data, I would recommend reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7611169/324364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7714677/324364).

Comment: Could I not just do p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(x = scatterPlotData[,1],y = scatterPlotData[,2]))?

Comment: @intl That _might_ work, but you shouldn't do it. `aes` is designed to do some sophisticated evaluation of its arguments. It is best not to mess with it. Always pass names of variables themselves, or simple functions of them (e.g. `log(variable)`,`factor(variable)`). Anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: OK, so I'll make variables for xScatter = scatterPlotData[,1] and yScatter = scatterPlotData[,2] and use these for p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(x = xScatter,y = yScatter)).

But, what then is the point of passing in scatterPlotData if it contains the data of the variables anyway?

Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: @intl Maybe I wasn't clear. `scatterPlotData` should be a data frame. Each column should have a name. Use **those** names, and make sure they are syntactically valid (i.e. no spaces).

Comment: Thank you, got it working. My issue, as you pointed out, was that I wasn't using the proper column names. I added labels by adding the labels to the overall dataframe and using its column name.

Answer (score 3):

Lose the inverted commas, at the moment you're making a plot of the text value... Having looked again, you will have problems with the brackets in your variable name (`Distance (bp)`). Change that to something without the brackets, then make the `ggplot` call without the inverted commas:

```
#Assuming Distance (bp) is the first column
names(scatterPlotData)[1] <- "Distance"
p <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(Distance, Intensity) + geom_point()
```

As for non-overlapping labels, this is a vexed issue with lots of discussion on SO - I think you'll not get great responses from such a vague question here.

Comment: The ... just signifies that there are a lot more similar values. And is there a conventional way of doing labels?

Comment: I described that poorly, I meant the inverted commas, not the dots in your data