# How to smartly place text labels beside points of different sizes in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a labeled bubble plot with `ggplot2` in R. Here is the simplified scenario:

I have a data frame with 4 variables: 3 quantitative variables, `x`, `y`, and `z`, and another variable that labels the points, `lab`.

I want to make a scatter plot, where the position is determined by `x` and `y`, and the size of the points is determined by `z`. I then want to place text labels *beside* the points (say, to the right of the point) without overlapping the text on top of the point.

If the points did not vary in size, I could try to simply modify the aesthetic of the `geom_text` layer by adding a scaling constant (e.g. `aes(x=x+1, y=y+1)`). However, even in this simple case, I am having a problem with positioning the text correctly because the points do not scale with the output dimensions of the plot. In other words, the size of the points remains constant in a 500x500 plot and a 1000x1000 plot - they do not scale up with the dimensions of the outputted plot.

Therefore, I think I have to scale the position of the label by the size (e.g. dimensions) of the output plot, or I have to get the radius of the points from `ggplot` somehow and shift my text labels. Is there a way to do this in `ggplot2`?

Here is some code:

```
# Stupid data
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), 
                 y=c(1,2,3), 
                 z=c(1,2,1),
                 lab=c("a","b","c"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Plot with bad label placement
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=z)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=lab), 
            colour="red") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 50), guide="none")
```

**EDIT:** I should mention, I tried `hjust` and `vjust` inside of geom_text, but it does not produce the desired effect.

```
# Trying hjust and vjust, but it doesn't look nice
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=z)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=lab), hjust=0, vjust=0.5, 
            colour="red") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 50), guide="none")
```

**EDIT:** I managed to get something that works for now, thanks to Henrik and shujaa. I will leave the question open just in case someone shares a more general solution.

Just a blurb of what I am using this for: I am plotting a map, and indicating the amount of precipitation at certain stations with a point that is sized proportionally to the amount of precipitation observed. I wanted to add a station label beside each point in an aesthetically pleasing manner. I will be making more of these plots for different regions, and my output plot may have a different resolution or scale (e.g. due to different projections) for each plot, so a general solution is desired. I might try my hand at creating a custom `position_jitter`, like baptiste suggested, if I have time during the weekend.

Comment: hjust and vjust offset the text with a distance linked to the fontsize, so it should scale better than data coordinates

Comment: @baptiste Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried `hjust` and `vjust`, but it did not produce the desired result. When I tried to position text to the right of the points (hjust=0, vjust=0.5), the text still overlaps the point because it starts from the middle of the point.

Comment: i see the problem now that I've run your code, maybe a new function could be written based on position_jitter()

Comment: @baptiste Is `position_jitter` aware of the output plot dimensions? That may be a good lead to a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intelligent point label placement in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611169/intelligent-point-label-placement-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that position_*** don't have access to the scales used by other layers, so it's a no go. You could make a clone of GeomText that shifts the labels according to the size mapped,
but it's a lot of effort for a very kludgy and fragile solution,

[image]

```
geom_shiftedtext <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
                       position = "identity", 
                       parse = FALSE, ...) { 
  GeomShiftedtext$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, position = position, 
               parse = parse, ...)
}
require(proto)
GeomShiftedtext <- proto(ggplot2:::GeomText, {
  objname <- "shiftedtext"
  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, ..., parse = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) {
    data <- remove_missing(data, na.rm, 
                           c("x", "y", "label"), name = "geom_shiftedtext")

    lab <- data$label
    if (parse) {
      lab <- parse(text = lab)
    }

    with(coord_transform(coordinates, data, scales),
         textGrob(lab, unit(x, "native") + unit(0.375* size, "mm"), 
                  unit(y, "native"), 
                  hjust=hjust, vjust=vjust, rot=angle, 
                  gp = gpar(col = alpha(colour, alpha), 
                            fontfamily = family, fontface = fontface, lineheight = lineheight))

         )
  }

})


df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), 
                 y=c(1,2,3), 
                 z=c(1.2,2,1),
                 lab=c("a","b","c"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=z), shape=1) + 
  geom_shiftedtext(aes(label=lab, size=z),
            hjust=0, colour="red") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 100), guide="none")
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try with my data. It looks promising from the example plot. Can you clarify what you mean by this being a "kludgy and fragile solution"?

Comment: well, for one thing it has this 0.375 constant that will not work well for other point shapes. It's very limited in scope, because the offset it hard-wired to the East, it's not elegant because it's corrupting the size aesthetic from its intended purpose, it copies a lot of internal code of ggplot2 that might be subject to future changes, etc.

Comment: Well, that being said, this was very helpful and your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very general solution, because you'll need to tweak it every time, but you should be able to add to the `x` value for the text some value that's linear depending on `z`.

I had luck with

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + 
    geom_point(aes(size=z)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=lab, x = x + .06 + .14 * (z - min(z))), 
              colour="red") +
    scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 50), guide="none")
```

but, as the font size depends on your window size, you would need to decide on your output size and tweak accordingly. I started with `x = x + .05 + 0 * (z-min(z))` and calibrated the intercept based on the smallest point, then when I was happy with that I adjusted the linear term for the biggest point.

Comment: This (kind of) works for my toy data provided in the question, but I was hoping for a more general solution so that I could use it on my data. If it turns out to be too difficult, I will probably implement an approach similar to yours and scale the x variable when plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative. Looks OK with your test data, but you need to check how general it is.

```
dodge <- abs(scale(df$z))/4

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = z)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x + dodge), label = df$lab, colour = "red") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 50), guide = "none")
```

**Update**
Just tried `position_jitter`, but the `width` argument only takes one value, so right now I am not sure how useful that function would be. But I would be happy to find that I am wrong. Example with another small data set:

```
df3 <- mtcars[1:10, ]
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = qsec), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_text(label = df3$carb, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 50), guide = "none")
```

Comment: I mashed together your idea with @shujaa's answer to get something that kind of works for my data at a specific resolution. It will have to do for now, but it would be really neat to find a general solution for future plots.