# How replicate Plot in R

Tags: r, plot

can you help me how to have data labels in my R chart

```
date = c(1.45,0.89,0.74,3.28)
plot(date,type = "l")
```

[image]

I need the percentages to be displayed

[image: how can i achieve this]

Comment: This tagged ggplot but you don't seem to be using ggplot. Do you have a specific requirement? Also, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611169/intelligent-point-label-placement-in-r or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624656/label-points-in-geom-point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text`.

First, though, I'll expand the axis limits to make room.

```r
plot(date, type = "l", xlim = c(0.5, 4.5), ylim = range(date) + c(-0.5, 0.5))
text(seq_along(date), date+0.2, paste(date, "%"))
```

[image: simple plot]

Arbitrary components:

- I expanded 0.5 below and 0.5 above the range of `date`, may need to play with this if your data changes
- I used `date + 0.2` to shift the numbers slightly above the points;

Comment: Depending on your real data, you may prefer to replace `paste(date,"%")` with `sprintf("%0.02f%%",date)` in order to limit the number of decimal places.