# Calculate width of text string in default font/size

Tags: r

Is it at all possible to calculate the width size (in inches) of a particular string in the default font ( `par()$family` ) , and default size ( `par()$ps` ).

Calculating the height seems relatively simple:

```
par()$ps * 1/72
```

The challenge with width is that it is dependent on the string itself.  A string of i's "iiiiii" is smaller than a string of o's "ooooooo"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the function `strwidth` in `base`

```
strwidth('this is cool', font = 12, units = 'in')
```

Comment: +1 Exactly so.  See also the "Health Warning" Andrie included in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730150/extent-of-boundary-of-text-in-r-plot/7730492#7730492) to a similar question.

Comment: Is there a reason why strheight("A",font=16,units="in") returns .18 and not .22 according to the formula I posted?

Comment: see the link in Josh's comment. It is a function of what your current graphics setting is.

Comment: I'm in the browser and strheight is returning .15.  par()$ps is 16.  Is my equation wrong?