# add a data.frame as textbox to a plot

Tags: r, plot, text

Is there an easier way to add a data.frame as a "textbox" to a plot? I did it "manually", using function `legend`.

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000)), xlab='x', ylab='y', lwd=1, main='Call', col='blue', type='l')
lines(density(rnorm(1000, 0, 2)), lty=3, col='red')
eo1 <- c(rnorm(1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1))
eo1 <- cbind(eo1, c(rnorm(1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1)))
colnames(eo1) <- c('contextA', 'contextB')
legend('topleft', legend=c(paste('medida', paste(colnames(eo1)[1:2], collapse='  '))
                           , paste('mean       ', paste(sprintf('%+.3f', eo1[2, 1:2]), collapse='     '))
                           , paste('sk            ', paste(sprintf('%+.3f', eo1[2, 1:2]), collapse='     '))
                           , paste('krtE         ', paste(sprintf('%+.3f', eo1[3, 1:2]), collapse='     '))
), horiz=F, cex=.7)
```

I could not see how [Extent of boundary of text in R plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730150/extent-of-boundary-of-text-in-r-plot/7730492#7730492) could help.
[image: plot(density(rnorm(1000)),xlab='x',ylab='y',lwd=1,main='Call',col='blue',type='l'); lines(density(rnorm(1000,0,2)),lty=3,col='red') eo1=cbind(rnorm(1),rnorm(1)); eo1=rbind(eo1,cbind(rnorm(1),rnorm(1))) eo1=rbind(eo1,cbind(rnorm(1),rnorm(1))) colnames(eo1)=c('contextA','contextB') legend('topleft',legend=c(paste('medida',paste(colnames(eo1)[1:2],collapse=' ')) ,paste('mean ',paste(sprintf('%+.3f',eo1[2,1:2]),collapse=' ')) ,paste('sk ',paste(sprintf('%+.3f',eo1[2,1:2]),collapse=' ')) ,paste('krtE ',paste(sprintf('%+.3f',eo1[3,1:2]),collapse=' ')) ),horiz=F,cex=.7)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about {plotrix}:

```
library(plotrix)

plot(1:10)
addtable2plot(head(iris), x = 1, y = 10, yjust = 0)
```

[image: plotrix example]

Answer (score 1):

You may elaborate on `sprntf`, for instance by using `\t`abstops instead of spaces, and use `text` in a `Map` instead of `legend`.

```
set.seed(42)

plot(density(rnorm(1000)), xlab='x', ylab='y', lwd=1, main='Call', col='blue', type='l')
lines(density(rnorm(1000, 0, 2)), lty=3, col='red')
eo1 <- c(rnorm(1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1))
eo1 <- cbind(eo1, c(rnorm(1), rnorm(1), rnorm(1)))
colnames(eo1) <- c('contextA', 'contextB')

leg <- c(sprintf('medida\t%s\t%s', colnames(eo1)[1], colnames(eo1)[2]),
         sprintf('mean\t%+.3f\t%+.3f', eo1[1, 1], eo1[2, 2]),
         sprintf('sk\t\t%+.3f\t%+.3f', eo1[2, 1], eo1[2, 2]),
         sprintf('krtE\t\t%+.3f\t%+.3f', eo1[3, 1], eo1[2, 2]))

Map(\(x, y, z) text(par()$usr[1] + .125, y, leg[x], adj=0, font=z, cex=.8), 
    seq_along(leg), rev(seq_along(leg) * .025) + .3, c(3, 1, 1, 1))
```

[image]

You can also try `eo1 <- format(round(eo1, 3))` and replace `%+.3f` by `%s`, which aligns the values (more or less) while avoiding the `+` sign.