# Calculate bounding box of text on plot including text below baseline

Tags: r, text, plot, par

I am attempting to draw words on horizontal bars in a bar plot so the top and bottom of the words just brush the top and bottom sides of the bar plot.  This boils down to being able to calculate a tight bounding box for text including the descenders and ascenders.  For example, consider

```
plot( 1:10, 1:10 )
text( 3, 7, "sample", adj=c(0,0), cex=3 )
sh = strheight( "sample" )
abline( h=c( 7, 7+3*sh  ) )
```

Note the top line hits the "l" just right.  The "p" descends through the bottom line.

How can I calculate a proper bottom line here?

Alternatively, how can I plot text so it fills a given height, such as the following:

```
plot( 1:10, 1:10 )
ht = 2
abline( h=c( 7, 7+ht ) )
sh = strheight( "sample" )
sh
text( 3, 7, "sample", adj=c(0,0), cex=2/sh )
```

This question is related to finding bounding boxes (see [related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234335/finding-the-bounding-box-of-plotted-text)).  Due to the descender issue, it does not seem to be the same the the solutions there do not seem to fully work.

Comment: Maybe you could make it an expression: `text(3, 7, ex <- expression("sample"), adj=c(0,0), cex=3 ); sh <- strheight(ex)`

Comment: Seems perfect, @lukeA - post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
plot( 1:10, 1:10 )
text(3, 7, ex <- expression("sample"), adj=c(0,0), cex=3 ) 
sh <- strheight(ex)
abline( h=c( 7, 7+3*sh  ) )
```

Comment: (+1) Note that on Windows this only worked for me when I plotted to a `png` device using cairo graphics (i.e. `png('x.png', type='cairo')`).